# ¿Cómo puedo evitar los saltos de linea no deseados en HTML?

Tags: html, vscode

En días pasados reinstalé todo mi entorno de desarrollo y durante los últimos días realizando pruebas me doy cuenta que Pettier está formateando el código de manera inusual, es decir, algunas etiquetas las abre y cierra con saltos de linea.

```
    <header
        ><img src="logo.png" height="68" width="68" alt="Logo del sitio web" />
        <h1>This is a test</h1>
    </header>
```

En este caso la etiqueta de apertura `header` la finaliza en la siguiente linea.

```
    <a
        href="link"
        target="_balnk"
        >(Source)</a
        ></p
    >
```

En este otra caso es mucho mas notorio, y se vuelve bastante confuso.

Anexo mi configuración de Prettier que he usado anteriormente y considero no tiene fallas:

```
    "prettier.bracketSameLine": true,
    "prettier.bracketSpacing": true,
    "prettier.embeddedLanguageFormatting": "auto",
    "prettier.htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "strict",
    "prettier.arrowParens": "always",
    "prettier.insertPragma": false,
    "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true,
    "prettier.printWidth": 120,
    "prettier.proseWrap": "preserve",
    "prettier.quoteProps": "as-needed",
    "prettier.requirePragma": false,
    "prettier.semi": true,
    "prettier.singleQuote": true,
    "prettier.trailingComma": "es5",
    "prettier.useTabs": true,
    "prettier.vueIndentScriptAndStyle": false,
    "prettier.tabWidth": 2,
```

Comment: [https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#html-whitespace-sensitivity]  .  De acuerdo a esta pagina, es recomendable el  `printWidth` en 80 , otra cosa que podrias intentar seria cambiar el  `htmlWhitespaceSensitivity` a  _''ignore''_